# Do you need c++ 17 for learning c++ from 2020?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-7, c++17, codeblocks

I'm using Window 7 OS, I'm Learning C++ for Competitive Programming. I downloaded a version of CodeBlocks but it does not have C++17 (it only has C++98 and C++0x). Is C++17 really important for Learning C++ [preferably for Competitive Programming] or can I carry with my pre-existing CodeBlocks Version? Also, if C++17 is Preferred can you please provide the source to Download C++17 IDE (Codeblocks or Visual Studio). A link would even be more welcomed.

Comment: If your computer won't support `Visual Studio 2019` you can use this link to get `Visual Studio 2017`... I wouldn't go any lower than version 2017... at least that way you can still use C++17. However, if your computer can support Visual Studio 2019, I would recommend that so that you can learn about and utilize all of the newer features that are in C++20 such as `concepts`, and other things... Here's the link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: You will have to create a Microsoft account, and from there you can get there `Community Editions` for free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++17 does not give you access to a new language, it is just an update to an existing language. Most of the competitive programming sites will have c++14 or c++17 running on their servers, so it is preferably good to have one. If you want a pre installed IDE then you can look at the latest version of **Visual Studio** (probably 2019). Or if you just want a compiler then you can look at **MinGW**.

> Download Visual Studio : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
> Download MinGW : https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/

Regarding **MinGW**, it is just a compiler, if you want to use it, then you have to install something like **Visual Studio Code, Sublime Text, Atom,** etc and then set it up yourself or look at some tutorials on YouTube. Lastly, if you have any other doubts, comment on this answer and I will be pleased to look into the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The version of CodeBlocks you have installed is not the latest. The latest official release (20.03) provides the bundle MinGW compiler version 8.1.0 which supports C++14 and C++17, I seem to remember. 
I advise you to install the IDE (CodeBlocks) and the compiler separately. 
By installing Msys2 you have the possibility to always update mingw to the latest version (the latest gcc (10.2) offers support for C++20, as well as C++17, 14 and 11).